# Fish shell; import config into main config

Tags: fish

My `~/.config/fish/config.fish` is getting gigantic.

What is the idiomatic way to write another file and "source" it from inside this file so my main config isn't so huge?

Can I make like a `~/.config/fish/config-work.fish` and add `source ~/.config/fish/config-work.fish` into my main config?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since version 2.3.0, fish automatically reads ~/.config/fish/conf.d/*.fish on startup, so you can also just use those.

Or you can manually `source` files.

Answer (score 3):

One strategy I use is to segregate functionality based on what machine I'm using.
 In my ~/.config/fish/config.fish I have:

```
set host_config ~/.config/fish/config.(hostname).fish
test -r $host_config; and source $host_config
```